# curly braces and parentheses for scala map

Tags: scala

```
 Array(7,8,9) map (x:Int=>x+1) //1).error, identifier expected but integer literal found.
 Array(7,8,9) map {x:Int=>x+1} //2) correct  
 Array(7,8,9) map ((x:Int)=>x+1) //3) correct
 Array(7,8,9) map (x=>x+1) //4 correct
 Array(7,8,9) map {x=>x+1} //5 correct
 Array(7,8,9) map x=>x+1   //6 error
```

I would ask for the above cases，why some work while others are not as the comments indicate

Comment: I've learned that there's a direct correlation between sounds of crickets and questions related to Scala's arcane syntax rules.  My guess is (1) provides an ambiguity that the parser can't resolve properly in "all cases".  Interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
 Array(7,8,9) map {x:Int=>x+1} //2) correct  
 Array(7,8,9) map {x=>x+1} //5 correct
```

From [Scala Specification Anonymous Function definition](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions):

> In the case of a single untyped formal parameter, (x) => e can be abbreviated to x => e. If an anonymous function (x: T) => e with a
>   single typed parameter appears as the result expression of a block, it
>   can be abbreviated to x: T => e.

and for type `Int`, **Scala** can infer this **Type** under this context.